# D3js v5 grouped bar chart data x.domain labels and data separated

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, data-visualization

I have data in the following format coming in as a variable.

```
var groupeddata = 
  [{ Title: "Dummy Data", ID: "46", RFU: 20291, Name: "Name1", barcolor: "#ff7f00"}, 
  {Title: "Dummy Data", ID: "50", RFU: 15000, Name: "Name2", barcolor: "#ff7f00"}, 
  {Title: "Dummy Data", ID: "40", RFU: 14000, Name: "Name3", barcolor: "#ff7f00"}, 
  {Title: "Dummy Data2", ID: "46", RFU: 21000, Name: "Name1", barcolor: "#8B008B"}, 
  {Title: "Dummy Data2", ID: "50", RFU: 18095, Name: "Name2", barcolor: "#8B008B"}, 
  {Title: "Dummy Data2", ID: "56", RFU: 27278, Name: "Name3", barcolor: "#8B008B"}];
```

I have been able to create grouped bar chart if the data is [grouped by ID using the d3.nest function as I discussed in a previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087395/d3js-v5-specifying-domains-from-nested-data-for-grouped-bar-charts): https://bl.ocks.org/Coola85/b05339b65a7f9b082ca210d307a3e469

However, if there are two bars with the same "Name" property values, and different IDs as in the case above, they appear far away. For example, Name3 shows a bar at ID 40 (row 3 of data) and at ID 56 (row 6 of data) (https://bl.ocks.org/Coola85/86391f03bab40b16bdc24f1eedfba35f/). 
Additionally, it would be fine if the x-axis tick labels were also simple numbers 1, 2, 3 instead of the ID numbers. 
I do not want the names to come on the x-axis tick labels, as the names would be too long to fit in the actual data-set.

I have been trying to do this for a while with no luck, and any help is appreciated.

**Update 1**
To clarify, here is the image of what I want it to look like:
[Ideal output. Note- the text and arrows which are dashed are only for 
reference and not desired in final output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DtLG.jpg)

Comment: Could you mock up what you want it to look like? I'm finding the question a little confusing at the moment...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thanks Ian for a response. I have updated the post with the image for you to take a look at what I desire as the output. Also note that the x-axis ticks are just 1, 2, and 3 and not the names. If I nest by names and then sort and present the data, the names come on the x-axis tick labels which is not desired as the names in final data are long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there - it's just that your `d3.nest` is incorrect. Your grouping on the `ID` at the moment, but looking at your expected output that's not needed anywhere.

Change your grouping to use `Name`:

```
var databyID = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Name; })
    .entries(groupeddata);
```

This produced the following which I think is exactly what you want [image]

Comment: Thanks Ian. Yes. I have reached this point by replacing d.ID to d.Name I am able to produce what you have. However, I do not want the labels below to be Name1, Name2, Name3. Instead I want them to be either IDs or just generic 1, 2, 3.

Comment: To replace them you're going to need some form of a lookup betwen `'1' ==> 'Name1'` etc. Can you just re-shape your data at the start? That'll be far the easiest way

Comment: After I sort the data, I could clone the databyID and then replace the keys retaining the order? Then send the new array with 1 2 3 into the d3js charting? Is this possible or is my logic flawed in some way? New to javascript not sure the exact function I would need to use to selectively replace all keys. Note- final dataset won't have "Name" it will have something totally random.